# How to display search results in an activity?

Tags: android, listview, searchview

What I am trying to achieve should work similar to Gmail android app's search functionality.

I have 'Today' as my main activity which contains a listview. This listview contains various types of items having different layout for each item. I have configured OnClicklisteners and OnLongClickListeners on each type of listitems inside my listadapter class. The methods which these listeners call are written in 'Today' activity class. For ex. following method EditThisNote is called on click.

```
public void EditThisNote(View v) {
    int noteId = Integer.valueOf(textView.getTag().toString());
    Note noteObject = dbHelper.getNoteObjectFor(noteId);
    new NoteEditor().execute(noteObject);
}

private class NoteEditor extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Note... notes) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Today.this, EditNote.class);
        intent.putExtra(ApplicationConstants.NOTE_OBJECT, notes[0]);
        startActivity(intent);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
    }
}
```

I have configured the search functionality using SearchView widget. I am displaying results of this search query as a ListView in a separate activity called `SearchResultsActivity`. I have used the same layouts that used in 'Today' activity for displaying the search results. Now I want user to be able to do the similar things on these list-items that he was able to do from my main activity.

How can I re-use the setup that I did in 'Today' activity?
Or Shall I just rewrite the above code in `SearchResultsActivity` and get it working?

I have tried calling the methods written in 'Today' from `SearchResultsActivity` but it's not possible.

Comment: have you considered http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a place to use Fragments. You put all of the logic/duplicate code in a Fragment. Then you can use this Fragment class in any Activity you want.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Also, editThisNote() is a class method so can only be called from an instance of a TodayActivity. So you can not call it from SearchResultsActivity.